# Python. sed -e expression #1: char 11: unterminated 's' command

Tags: python, shell, sed

I've got a problem with executing a shell command in python. Here is some part of my code which is causing the error:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["cat input.txt |apertium -d. kaz-morph|\
    sed -e 's/\$\W*\^/$\n^/g'| cut -f2 -d'/'|cut -f1 -d '<'|\
    awk '{print tolower($0)}'|sort -u>output.txt"], shell=True, stdout=f1)
```

Still getting the error: unterminated 's' command.

Hope you will help me because I couldn't solve it for 10 days :(

p.s. sorry for my english

Comment: also, with `shell=True`, just a string is fine, no need to use list of string

Comment: It might be cleaner to put that script into a separate file, e.g. `~/morph-and-sort.sh` and do `chmod +x ~/morph-and-sort.sh` and change the python to `Popen(["~/morph-and-sort.sh"], shell=True,stdout=f1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'\n'` must be `'\\n'`, or else it is interpreted as a line break, which results in an unterminated string `"cat input.txt |apertium -d. kaz-morph|sed -e 's/\$\W*\^/$"`.

Alternatively, mark the string as raw: `r"cat input.txt |apertium ...."`.